# Babel removes jsdoc header comments. How to force it to keep them?

Tags: babeljs, jsdoc

I have a .ts file with following code:

```
/**
 * @ab 3.0
 * @xy 
 */

import * as myInterface from "@root/common/interface/interfaces";
...
```

I want to have the comment header at the very top of the .js file, however it either disappears in some cases or is being moved to the middle of the code in other cases. Does anyone have any idea how to configure babel to transpile it in a correct way? I am using babelrc.